# Failed to get kubelets cgroup

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Am trying to setup `kubernetes` in `centos` machine, kubelets start is giving me this error.

> Failed to get kubelets cgroup: cpu and memory cgroup hierarchy not
>   unified. Cpu:/, memory: /system.slice/kubelet.service.

The cgroup driver I mentioned is systemd for both docker and kubernetes

`Docker` version 1.13.1
`Kubernetes` version 1.15.2

Can any one suggest the solution.

Comment: please include the versions you use

Comment: Hi Linpy, 
Docker version 1.13.1
Kubernetes version 1.15.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78950) is fixed in a commit but still not merged see [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/80121)

you may try this work around:

```
sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/kubelet
```

add at the end of DAEMON_ARGS string:

```
 --runtime-cgroups=/systemd/system.slice --kubelet-cgroups=/systemd/system.slice
```

restart:

```
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
```

or :

adding a file in : `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/11-cgroups.conf`

which contains:

```
[Service]
CPUAccounting=true
MemoryAccounting=true
```

then reload and restart

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart kubelet
```

Comment: What will be the solution.. the prior version shall I go or any other solution