# Two coredns Pods in k8s cluster are in pending state

Tags: docker, kubernetes

```
kube-system   coredns-f68dcb75-f6smn           0/1     Pending   0          34m
kube-system   coredns-f68dcb75-npc48           0/1     Pending   0          34m
kube-system   etcd-master                      1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master            1/1     Running   0          34m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master   1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-lngrx      1/1     Running   1          32m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-qz2gn      1/1     Running   0          32m
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-w5lpc      1/1     Running   0          34m
kube-system   kube-proxy-9l9nv                 1/1     Running   0          32m
kube-system   kube-proxy-hvd5g                 1/1     Running   0          32m
kube-system   kube-proxy-vdgth                 1/1     Running   0          34m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master            1/1     Running   0          33m
```

I am using the latest k8s version: 1.16.0.

`kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --image-repository=<some-repo> --token=TOKEN --apiserver-advertise-address=<IP> --kubernetes-version=1.16.0`

This is the command I am using to initialize the cluster

The current state of the cluster.

```
master   NotReady   master   42m   v1.16.0
slave1   NotReady   <none>   39m   v1.16.0
slave2   NotReady   <none>   39m   v1.16.0
```

Please comment if you need any other info.

Comment: check first why nodes are in NotReady state

Comment: check `kubectl describe nodes`

Comment: ```Failed to update Node Allocatable Limits ["kubepods"]: failed to set supported cgroup subsystems for cgroup [kubepods]: failed to find subsystem mount for required subsystem: pids```

Comment: This error, ```FailedNodeAllocatableEnforcement``` is in all the 3 nodes: master and both slaves.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456667/failed-to-get-kubelets-cgroup/57456786#57456786

Comment: @LinPy, that didn't help.

Comment: Check my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024643/kubernetes-master-node-not-ready-state), meaby that's gonna work for you too.

Comment: @SidhuMooseWala Did it work? Or u still have this problem?

Comment: @jt97 Yes! Your solution helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait for  `k8s v1.17.0` or update your current installaion, this issue fixed in [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/08c258add9b9b0be4597415f0add3d8fb627ec4b)

orginal [Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/79046)

Comment: I think they merged the fix also to `master` branch and  try to update your installaion

Comment: Well, I am using the latest one only. So I'll wait for the new version.